# Using ObjectInputStream to store Objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, io, stream

I want to take the "computer" objects from the "computers.dat" file and put them into an ArrayList, then call the computer.toString() method to display them.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadComputers {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("computers.dat");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    ArrayList <Computer> comp;
    comp = (ArrayList <Computer>)ois.readObject(); 


  for (int i = 0; i < comp.size(); i++) {
      String computer = comp.get(i).toString();
      System.out.println(computer);
  }
    ois.close();
 }
}
```

For the record, the computer class has implemented the Serializable interface, in case you were wondering if that was the problem

When I run the program I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: thibodeau17.Computer
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at thibodeau17.ReadComputers.main(ReadComputers.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: thibodeau17.Computer
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at thibodeau17.StoreComputers.main(StoreComputers.java:23)
```

Comment: Exception said that class Computer can't be serialized.

Comment: Do all members of `Computer` implement Serializable?

Comment: @Lars Computer is only one class with some declarations. There is a StoreCompter class that writes them to a file and a ReadComputer class which gets them from the .dat file. The only one that implemented Serializable is Computer but when I did it to the other two it didn't affect anything

Comment: You got a similar `IOException` when you *wrote* this file, and you have completely ignored it. Your `thibodeau17.Computer` class isn't serializable, or it wasn't when you wrote the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadComputers {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

try{

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("computers.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Object obj = ois.readObject();
            ArrayList<Computer> computers = (ArrayList<Computer>) obj;

            for (Computer c : computers) {
                System.out.println(c.toString());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I borrowed code from a couple different sources around the web and my textbook, but to anyone who was curious for an answer here it is. Thank you to all that helped.

Comment: @EJP You're wrong. My computer class already implemented Serializable, and nothing was changed to it to make the program successfully compile. It was just a change in this class. Thank you for contributing literally nothing to this already-answered question.